# Xpath to append ids form an sequence string and assigning in a string

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xquery

Can you please help me to put this elements from a node in single quotes and separated by comma
Example.  <sf:Id>0018000000yDQ82AAG</sf:Id> <sf:AccountNumber>835</sf:AccountNumber> <sf:Direct_Models_Ids__c>a1H800000020uWVEAY;a1H800000020uVzEAI;a1H800000020uWUEAY;a1H800000020uX2EAI;</sf:Direct_Models_Ids__c>

<F_model_ids>('a1H800000020uWVEAY','a1H800000020uVzEAI','a1H800000020uWUEAY','a1H800000020uX2EAI')</F_model_ids>

Can suggest how to do this using xpath

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are looking for the `tokenize()` function available in XPath 2.0 and above. But without a [mcve] I can only guess.

Comment: <records xsi:type="sf:Account">
      <sf:Id>0018000000yDQ82AAG</sf:Id>
      <sf:AccountNumber>835</sf:AccountNumber>
      <sf:Direct_Models_Ids__c>a1H800000020uWVEAY;a1H800000020uVzEAI;a1H800000020uWUEAY;a1H800000020uX2EAI;</sf:Direct_Models_Ids__c>
   </records>

Comment: for above models i need to store they in a string as ('a1H800000020uWVEAY','a1H800000020uVzEAI','a1H800000020uWUEAY','a1H800000020uX2EAI')

Comment: i need to do this using xpath

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: yep can you help me with this?

Comment: concat('(',"'",string-join(tokenize("a1H800000020uWVEAY;a1H800000020uVzEAI;", ';'),"','"),"'",')') I tried this but result was not useful

Comment: here the result ('a1H800000020uWVEAY','a1H800000020uVzEAI','')

Comment: **Please stop posting code in comments.**  I cannot help you if I don't see an example of the input and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

An XPath 3.1 expression to tokenize, concat, string-join, concat is e.g.

```
'(' || (. => tokenize(';'))[normalize-space()] ! ("'" || . || "'") => string-join(',') || ')'
```

see it in context at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6ym